# Is the twisted Sphere homeomorphic to the standard sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Given a diffeomorphism $f:S^n\to S^n$, gluing the boundaries of two copies of the standard disk $D^n$ together by $f$ yields a manifold called a twisted sphere (with twist f). In general we can't get it's a diffeomorphic sphere, but can we prove that it's homeomorphic to the standard sphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently yes, a twisted sphere is homeomorphic even when not diffeomorphic to the standard sphere, as it is then an example of an *exotic sphere*.  And you can read about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere).

Note that in some dimensions there are no exotic spheres.   Dimension $4$ is still up in the air.

Comment: It is better than just an example of an exotic sphere. In dimension 5, all exotic spheres are twisted-sphere, but in dimension less than 3, there are no exotic sphere (this is easy in dimension less than 2 and a consequence of the Poincaré-Perelman theorem in dimension 3), so just the case of the dimension 4 is left open.

Comment: I meant, "in dimension at least 5"*, not just 5.

Comment: Thanks.   I was just adjusting my answer.  Hopefully it's a little better now.  @C.Falcon

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the twisted-sphere $D_1\cup_fD_2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{S}^n$ and a homeomorphism is explicitly given by
$$h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lrr}x & \textrm{if }x\in D_1,\\\|x\|f\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right) & \textrm{if }x\in D_2\setminus\{0\},\\0 & \textrm{if }x=0\in D_2,\end{array}\right.$$
where $h\colon D_1\cup_{\operatorname{id}}D_2\colon\to D_1\cup_fD_2$.

To be perfectly rigorous, you still have to show that $D_1\cup_{\operatorname{id}}D_2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{S}^n$, but this is fairly standard and can be achieved by the maps
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\left(x_1,\ldots,x_n,\pm\sqrt{1-{x_1}^2-\ldots-{x_n}^2}\right).$$

Comment: thank you. So the boundary function $f$ completely determines the twisted sphere. Now can we give $f$ a condition such that the twisted sphere is diffeomorphic to the standard sphere?

Comment: Yes, it is easily seen that $D_1\cup_f D_2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbf{S}^n$ if, and only if, $f$ is isotopic to the identity through diffeomorphisms of $\mathbf{S}^n$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your patience.

Comment: @C.Falcon:  I agree that if a diffeo is isotopic to the identity, then the resulting sphere is standard, but I don't think the converse is known since, e.g. we haven't resolved the smooth Poincare conjecture in dim 4.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I believe the $h$-cobordism ensures that exotic spheres comes from twisted-spheres only in dimension greater than $5$, but in lower dimension the exotic differential structures can come from other constructions, am I wrong? Though, I agree that in dimension 4, due to Cerf's theorem, twisted-sphere are useless to disprove the Poincaré's conjecture.

Comment: I agree with everything you just wrote, but it doesn't seem to resolve my initial comment.  Even if all exotic spheres arise as twisted spheres (in high enough dimension) why can't non-isotopic diffeos occasionally give the same sphere on accident?  In fact, this does happen: if we glue by an orientation reversing linear map, we get a standard sphere.  I don't know that this *can* happen for two non-isotopic orientation-preserving diffeos, but I also don't know that it *can't* happen.

Comment: I just did some googling and you were right.  Apparently, it's a result of Cerf that in high enough dimensions, two twisted spheres are diffeo iff the (orientation preserving) gluing maps are isotopic.  Sorry for derailing your post!

Comment: @JasonDeVito Can you tell me where can I find the result of Cerf? Thanks.